# List of public IPs of NAT Gateways in VPC

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to get a list of the public IPs of the NAT gateways in a VPC, using a Terraform data source?

An example of getting a list of subnet ids is shown [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html#example-usage), but it is predicated on the aws_subnet_ids data source, which returns a list to start with.

We've got NAT gateways per private subnet.  I'm not finding a way to get the list of NAT gateways in a vpc and then get the public IPs from that list.

Has anyone needed and/or solved this issue?

Comment: `nat_gateway_id = "${aws_nat_gateway.NATGW.id}"`?

Answer (score 2):

This workaround worked for me
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7575

My code sample

```
data "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gw" {
 for_each = toset(module.vpc.public_subnets)
 subnet_id = each.value
}
```

Get public IP of NAT to add as source for an Security group

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_https"{
 type                     = "ingress"
 security_group_id        = module.sg.id
 from_port                = "443"
 to_port                  = "443"
 protocol                 = "tcp"
 cidr_blocks              = [ for v in data.aws_nat_gateway.nat_gw : format("${v.public_ip}%s", "/32") ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    shell = {
      source = "scottwinkler/shell"
      version = "1.7.10"
    }
  }
}

provider "shell" {
  # Configuration options
}

data "shell_script" "nat_gateways" {
  lifecycle_commands {
    read = <<-EOF
      aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --region ${var.region}
    EOF
  }
}

locals {
  nat_gw_ips = flatten([
    for elem in jsondecode(data.shell_script.nat_gateways.output.NatGateways):
      format("${elem.NatGatewayAddresses[0].PublicIp}%s", "/32")
  ])
}
output "natgwips" {
  value = local.nat_gw_ips
}
```